# Unicode 2044, bug on Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: unicode

Take a look at the following image:

[image]

The numbers 789 are smaller than the others. That's because I inserted a slash using the Unicode 2044 through the CSS pseudo-element `:before` → `content: "\2044"`.

It seems the Unicode 2044 is used to write more complex fractions than ½, ⅔, ⅖, etc. But it is not working on Google Chrome. So, is there a bug on Firefox/Chrome?

Which is the expected behavior for this Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either rendering is acceptable. From Section 6.2 of the Unicode Standard:

> Such a fraction should be displayed as a unit, such as ¾ [or split]. The precise choice of display can depend on additional formatting information.
>
> If the displaying software is incapable of mapping the fraction to a unit, then it can also be displayed as a simple linear sequence as a fallback (for example, 3/4).

In general, cased and split fraction rendering support for `U+2044` is quite rare.